# How to check if value exists in Mysql table IN WPF

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I want to check if values exist in a mysql table with wpf but i can't find a way! Please Help Me!
(I don't have code, that's what i'm searching for.)
Example:

```
text in the textbox: 123456789
if (value exists){
Messagebox.Show("the value exists!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all we must need to know how your database structure is.

But maybe this snippet could help you to solve your problem:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 'found'
        ELSE 'not-found'
    END
FROM test
WHERE t='123456789';
```

t is the column where you look for your value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query for that

```
SELECT COUNT(ID)  FROM STUDENT WHERE ID='1';
```

if the count would be 0 then data doesn't exist in the table if it is greater than 0 then id exists

Here I have taken an example of the Student table you can convert this query as per your requirement

and In the if clause, you can make this condition will work fine